# Exit / Close a PWA when Back buttons are used

Tags: javascript, android, android-manifest, progressive-web-apps

Is their any way to close a PWA (or TWA) programmatically, when the user hits the back button on an android phone twice, like the way it works for native apps ? In the current state the PWA goes through all visited pages. Maybe I miss something? Any help, hints or code samples are welcome.

Comment: You can add cordova to your project ?

Comment: No add. frameworks/SDKs are added, its a PWA, which is reused as a TWA Play Store package. Their is no access to native APIs.